# Trigger IIS AppPool recycle within a WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I am working on a web service that interacts with an unstable third-party C++ DLL.

It frequently throws `AccessViolationException` (i.e., a crash within the DLL) and the only way to recover is to recycle the app pool.

Is there a way to programmatically recycle the app pool?

Note: I tried to change timestamps of my .NET DLLs and web.config but that doesn't seem to do enough to get the w3wp.exe process to unload the native C++ DLL. I can't touch the C++ DLL because it comes back with an error: "the DLL is in use".

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the box, you can use appcmd.exe :

```
C:\dev>\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe apppool  /?
Administration of application pools

APPCMD (command) APPPOOL <identifier> <-parameter1:value1 ...>

Supported commands:

  list      List application pools
  set       Configure application pool
  add       Add new application pool
  delete    Delete application pool
  start     Start application pool
  stop      Stop application pool
  recycle   Recycle application pool

(To get help for each command use /?, e.g. 'appcmd.exe add site /?'.)
```

To use that from within code you'd need to use `System.Diagnostics.Process` to run  the appropriate recycle command.